# How to use slog with custom handler?

Tags: go

I am new to Golang and working on a POC. I want to use slog for structured logging. So far, I have written a 'logger.go' file in 'logger' package and would like to know how can I use customized logger 'NewSlogHandler' in other go files present in different packages (for e.g. main, database etc.)

```
package logger

import (
    "log/slog"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

type SlogHandler struct {
    slogger slog.Logger
}

func (h *SlogHandler) NewSlogHandler(rec slog.Record) slog.Logger {
    slogHandler := slog.NewJSONHandler(os.Stdout, &slog.HandlerOptions{
        Level:     rec.Level,
        AddSource: true,
        ReplaceAttr: func(groups []string, a slog.Attr) slog.Attr {
            if a.Key == slog.TimeKey {
                a.Key = "UTCTime"
                a.Value = slog.TimeValue(time.Now().UTC())
            }
            return a
        },
    }).WithAttrs([]slog.Attr{
        slog.Group("app_details",
            slog.Int("pid", os.Getpid()),
            slog.String("go_version", runtime.Version()),
        ),
    })
    slogger := slog.New(slogHandler)
    slog.SetDefault(slogger)

    return *slogger
}
```

Working Code:

```
package logger

import (
    "log/slog"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

func NewSlogHandler() slog.Logger {
    hostname, err := os.Hostname()
    if err != nil {
        hostname = ""
        slog.Error("could not get hostname")
    }
    logHandler := slog.NewJSONHandler(os.Stdout, &slog.HandlerOptions{
        Level:     slog.LevelDebug,
        AddSource: true,
        ReplaceAttr: func(groups []string, a slog.Attr) slog.Attr {
            if a.Key == slog.TimeKey {
                a.Key = "UTCTime"
                a.Value = slog.TimeValue(time.Now().UTC())
            }
            return a
        },
    }).WithAttrs([]slog.Attr{
        slog.Group("app_details",
            slog.Int("pid", os.Getpid()),
            slog.String("hostname", hostname),
            slog.String("go_version", runtime.Version()),
        ),
    })
    logger := slog.New(logHandler)
    slog.SetDefault(logger)

    return *logger
}
```

Comment: Why is NewSlogHandler a method on an unused type? It probably is the best you work through the Tour of Go once more as using functions (or types and methods) across packages is something fundamental.

Comment: @Volker I’m not sure suggesting the entire Tour of Go is useful. Let’s try to narrow in on what OP is looking for help on. It’s an unused type in the file because OP said they want to use it in other packages and that it is exported is conducive to that. @\Ranjeet Perhaps [edit] your question with what you have so far in another package as an example of how you are trying to use the struct you have created here and your expected results that you are unable to achieve.

Comment: @grg You can use functions in other packages too. The code is broken and lacks basic understanding on how to write Go code (e.g. NewSlogHandler shouldn't be a method on SlogHandler). I'm not talking about `type SlogHandler` being unused but the receiver `h`.

Comment: @Volker Thank you for your time and inputs. I found what was wrong with the code and updated it in my post. As I said, I just started to learn go and slog is pretty new to find some help hence the trouble.

Comment: @grg Thanks for the help. I was planning to customize logging for DB, File, HTTP errors but after messing up realized that its better to do one thing at a time till I have better understanding of GO.

Comment: The question "[H]ow can I use customized logger 'NewSlogHandler' in other go files present in different packages[?]" is explained in detail in the Tour of Go and is the very fundamental thing about writing Go code and has literally **nothing** to do with slog. This either is a XY problem or you just should work through the introductionary material.